# Time efficient alternative to for-loops for manual sampling from timelines in R

Tags: r, for-loop, processing-efficiency

So I have sampled a set of lakes at x timepoints throughout the year. I also have deployed loggers etc. in the water and I want to use daily averages from these loggers, at the timepoint of the visit to x days/hours before. Sometimes I also just grab the a sample for the timepoint of the visit.

This is my solution, it works just fine but since I experiment alot with some model assumptions and perform sensitivity analyses it operates unsatisfactory slow.

I seem to have solved most of my R problems with loops and I often encounter more efficient scripts, it would be very interesting to see some more effective alternatives to my code.

Below code just generates some dummy data..

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

do.pct.sat <- function(x,y,z){
  t <- x
  do <- y
  p <- z
  atm <- (p*100)/101325
  do.sat <- atm*exp(-139.34411+157570.1/(t+273.15)-66423080/(t+273.15)^2+12438000000/(t+273.15)^3-862194900000/(t+273.15)^4)
  do.pct.sat <- (do/do.sat)*100
  return(do.pct.sat)
}#function for calculating the % oxygen saturation

#here's some dummy date resembling real data
date.initial <- as.POSIXct("2022-06-01")#deployment date
date.end <- as.POSIXct("2022-10-01")#date of retrieval
id <- c("a","b","c")#lake id
lake <- list()#make dataset list for each lake
s <- list()#list of dataframes for the samples from the lake logger timelines

#loop below generates dummy data. this is not part of the real script that I want to improve.
for(i in 1:3){
  datetime <- seq(from = date.initial,to = date.end,by=10*60)#10 minute intervals from deploy to retrieve
  l <- length(datetime)#vector length of datetime
  #set dummy data
  do <- rnorm(l,mean = 10,sd=3)#o2 conc.
  pressure <- rnorm(l,mean = 980,sd=50)#baro pressure
  temp <- rnorm(l,mean=15,sd=5)#water temp
  k.z <- rnorm(l,mean=0.35,sd=0.1)#gas exchange koeff / mixed layer depth
  dosat.pct <- do.pct.sat(temp,do,pressure)#oxygen sat in %
  
  iso <- as.data.frame(cbind(datetime,do,dosat.pct,temp,pressure,k.z))#bind dummy dataframe to resemble real data
  iso$datetime <- as.POSIXct(iso$datetime,origin = "1970-01-01")
  
  lake[[i]] <- iso#save the data frame to the lake logger list
  samples <- as.POSIXct(sample((date.initial+5*24*60*60):date.end, 7, replace=FALSE),origin = "1970-01-01")#randomize 7 timepoints
  s[[i]] <- as.data.frame(samples)#save it in empty data frame
  s[[i]]$lake <- id[i]
}
names(lake) <- id
samples <- bind_rows(s) 

samples$samples <- round_date(samples$samples,unit="10 minutes")#rounds my random samples to closest 10 minute
```

Below is the function that I want to effectivize (same library). I think it operates slow because I take one date at a time, before taking the next;

```
    sample.lakes <- function(average=3){

  dts <- list()#empty list
  for(i in 1:length(lake)){
    print(id[i])
    data = lake[[i]]
    y <- samples[grepl(id[i],samples$lake),]
    
    dates <- y$samples
    #empty vectors to fill with values sampled in loop
    avg.kz <- vector()
    sd.kz <- vector()
    do.mgl <- vector()
    dosat.pct <- vector()
    temp.c <- vector()
    for (k in 1:length(dates)){
      print(k)
      #below I filter the logger data to contain timepoint of sampling minus number of days I want the average from 'averages'.
      prior.days = filter(data, datetime > as.POSIXct(dates[k])-(24*60*60)*average & datetime < as.POSIXct(dates[k]))
      #fill the empty vectors with value I desire, mean and sd k.z and point sample of the other variables. 
      avg.kz[k] = mean(prior.days$k.z)
      sd.kz[k] = sd(prior.days$k.z)
      temp.c[k] <- data[grepl(dates[k],data$datetime),]$temp
      do.mgl[k] <- data[grepl(dates[k],data$datetime),]$do
      dosat.pct[k] <- data[grepl(dates[k],data$datetime),]$dosat.pct

      
      
    }
    sd.kz[is.na(sd.kz)] <- 0
    
    #add them to data frame y
    y$dosat.pct <- dosat.pct
    y$do.mgl <- do.mgl
    y$temp.c <- temp.c
    y$avg.kz <- avg.kz
    y$sd.kz <- sd.kz
    
    dts[[i]] <- y#add to single-row dataframe
  }
  iso <- bind_rows(dts)#make a complete dataframe with samples.

  return(iso)
  
}

iso <- sample.lakes(average=4)#do not set average to > 5 in this example script
```

I would appreciaty any suggestions alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that this part using `grepl`:

```
data[grepl(dates[k],data$datetime),]
```

inside your inner `for` loop is slow.

Couldn't you instead try just seeing if the datetimes are the same with `==`?

In addition, you only need to subset `data` once.

Try this as an alternative:

```
for (k in 1:length(dates)){
  print(k)
  
  prior.days = filter(data, datetime > as.POSIXct(dates[k])-(24*60*60)*average & datetime < as.POSIXct(dates[k]))
  
  avg.kz[k] = mean(prior.days$k.z)
  sd.kz[k] = sd(prior.days$k.z)
  
  sub_data <- data[data$datetime == dates[k], ]
  
  temp.c[k] <- sub_data$temp
  do.mgl[k] <- sub_data$do
  dosat.pct[k] <- sub_data$dosat.pct
}
```

Comment: Original code: 4.778444 secs
Your modification: 1.157542 secs

This is clearly an improvement to my for-loop. Yet I still think there's possibly even more efficient alternatives with some apply family function? Or something within the foreach package perhaps. I'll do some reading.

Anyhow, your answer is extremely useful, thank you very much!